# AWS Unable to connect to the Kubernetes API server on port 6443 - ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am encountering connectivity issues with the Kubernetes API server, specifically regarding access to port 6443. Despite the port being open and the server running, attempts to connect to the API server at 172.31.30.30:6443 are being refused. Testing with telnet also confirmed that the connection to this port is being refused

Problem: Unable to connect to the Kubernetes API server on port 6443.

IP Address:

172.31.30.30 controlplane

172.31.25.60 worker-1

172.31.36.75 worker-2

Port: 6443 Error Message: "The connection to the server 172.31.30.30:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?"

I've verified that the kubelet service is active and running, and initial troubleshooting steps, including checking the iptables rules, have been performed. However, the issue persists, suggesting a potential problem with the firewall configuration not explicitly allowing traffic on port 6443.

I was on the call with AWS support and they confirmed that security groups have the correct access

There are no issues with any of the VPC components for this EC2 instance. Total info as follows: - Security Group allows all inbound traffic from 172.31.0.0/16 and allows all outbound traffic. - Network ACL is open for all incoming/outgoing traffic. - Route Table routes VPC traffic 172.31.0.0/16 locally.